# How to get current week date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem getting the current week date in javascript. I wrote the following code to get the current week's date, It was working well but it seems it sometimes returns the next week's date. I could not understand where is the problem.
any help would be appreciated.

**This is my code:**

```
let curr = new Date();
let week = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i;
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  week.push(day);

};
console.log(week)
```

**The output:**

```
['2022-06-13', '2022-06-14', '2022-06-15', '2022-06-16', '2022-06-17', '2022-06-18', '2022-06-19']
```

**but today's date is `6/12/2022`, but the above date started from `13/06/2022`**

**Source:**
[here](https://medium.com/@quynh.totuan/how-to-get-the-current-week-in-javascript-9e64d45a9a08)

Comment: what is "current week date"? Ie what is the expected outcome if you eecute this code on the 2022-06-12 and whats the expected outcome when you execute this code on the 2022-06-15?

Comment: Do you want all dates of the current week (ie either SUN -> SAT or MON->SUN, if yes, which one) or do you just want the next seven dates from today?

Comment: I want the previous seven-date from today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you must take into consideration when current day is sunday to get current week first day (monday).

```js
let curr = new Date();
let week = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i;
  
  if (curr.getDay() === 0){
    first = curr.getDate() - 6;
  }
  let day = new     Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  week.push(day);

};
console.log(week)
```

Comment: you got my Idea, thank you.

Comment: dose this code works correct for weeks for all months, when month is 30 days or 31 days?

Comment: As far I know it should work. Do you have any problem with it?

Comment: No, Just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `+i` you are adding numbers 1 to 7 to your `first` variable. Now since the week starts from `Sunday=0`, you do not need to add an offset.

Just iterate loop from `0` to `6`:

```js
let curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
let week = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate()  - curr.getDay() + i;
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  week.push(day);

};
console.log(week)
```

**[Edit]** : If you want to get from 7 days ago, you can change how you initialize your `curr` variable.

From this :

```
let curr = new Date();
```

to this:

```
let curr = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

I use the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to get the epoch of today's date and subtract exactly the milliseconds passed in 7 days (or 1 week).

Comment: your code is correct, but I want to get the previous seven days from today what should I do?

Comment: @ZiaYamin made the change

Answer (score 0):

Start the for loop from 0

Like so

```js
let curr = new Date();
let week = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + I;
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  week.push(day);

};
console.log(week)
```

Remember, if you start from 1 and add 1 to the current date it will return tomorrow, and if you add 0 to today it retustns this date.

Comment: Your code is printing 8 days instead of 7 ...

Comment: See edit, forgot to remove his =

Answer (score 0):

**You can use moment.js library**

```js
let week = [];
let firstDayOfWeek = moment().startOf('week');

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  week.push(moment(firstDayOfWeek).add(i, 'd'));
};

console.log(week)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: New uses of momentjs are not advised, even by the authors. https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/